# How Can NodeJS and ExpressJS throw error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

The web app uses express for the server, Nodejs as the language, MongoDB as the database and mongoose as the wrapper. Express is running a server at port 3000 and I'm trying to implement a basic CRUD for a collection.
I use Newrelic to generate graphs and I see when the express throw error the response time server is rising up
for example :

```
User.findOne({ $or: [{ email: { $regex: new RegExp(email, 'i') } }, { userLogin: { $regex: new RegExp(userLogin, 'i') } }] }, 'id').exec()
    .then(results => {
        if (results) { throw new APIError('email_taken') } 
        else { return results }
  }).then(result => {
      res.status(201).success(result)
    }, error => {
      res.error(error)
    })
```

I really don't understand why the server time is rising up when ExpressJS throw an error like this.
I want to know if my method has an error or if there is another method better. 
And Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the ExpressJS documentation on [error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) it states that

> Errors that occur in synchronous code inside route handlers and
>   middleware require no extra work. If synchronous code throws an error,
>   then Express will catch and process it.

But

> For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route
>   handlers and middleware, you must pass them to the next() function,
>   where Express will catch and process them.

Since your database operation is asynchronous by nature, you should always pass the error to next() to handle it properly

Example

```
app.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile("/file-does-not-exist", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      next(err); // Pass errors to Express.
    }
    else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I really use it
`app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  res.success = function (obj) { res.send(APIResponse(obj)) }
  res.error = function (param1, param2) {
    let error
    if (param1.constructor === APIError) { error = param1 } else if (typeof (param1) === 'string') { error = new APIError(param1, param2) } else { error = new APIError('unknown') }

    res.status(error.status).send({
      'success': false,
      'error': {
        'code': error.code,
        'message': error.message
      }
    })
  }
  next()
})`

Comment: What do you mean you use it? I've gone through the code that you've commented, but what I am trying to say is, due to asynchronous nature of task, pass error to next()

Comment: Can you correct this code
`User.findOne({ $or: [{ email: { $regex: new RegExp(email, 'i') } }, { userLogin: { $regex: new RegExp(userLogin, 'i') } }] }, 'id').exec()
    .then(results => {
        if (results) { throw new APIError('email_taken') } 
        else { return results }
  }).then(result => {
      res.status(201).success(result)
    }, error => {
      res.error(error)
    })`

Comment: module.exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ $or: [{ 'auth.local.email': emailOrUserLogin }, { 'auth.local.userLogin': emailOrUserLogin }] }).exec()
  .then(results => {
        if (results) {
          return results
        } else {
          return next(new APIError('login_failed'))
        }
      })
}